# how to use sunburst plot from plotly to display the mean of each branch and not the sum/total?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the sunburst plot from Plotly but to display the average value of each group and subgroup and not the sum because my data points are rates.

is there a way I can get the plot for the averages ?

this is the plot I got
[image]

I checked if it is displaying sums using groupby :
[image]

but i want the values to be these
[image]